# insert multiple checkbox values into mysql field but add space between each one?

Tags: php, mysql

i am allowing my user to insert either one or 4 checkbox values into one field in my database, and later on want to be able to retrieve this data by doing a query for the each of those words, however, when more than one value is inserted into my field it separates these with a comma, which is fine but how do i seperate the words with a space? so i can later on do a search in my query for values containing 'mechanical' or 'non_mechanical' etc.

heres how it is being stored

```
mechanical,non_mechanical
```

also would the comma stop me doing a query for all containing the value of 'mechanical' for example as it would have a comma on the end?

html:

```
<p>mechanical</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="scope_type[]" value="mechanical" onClick="showMore(this);">


<p>Non-Mechanical Hire</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="scope_type[]" value="non_mechanical" onClick="showMoreMore(this);">


<p>Tools</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="scope_type[]" value="tools"  onClick="showMoreMoreMore(this);">

<p>Accessories</p>
<input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="scope_type[]" value="accessories"  onClick="showMoreMoreMoreMore(this);">
```

mysql:

```
<?php
session_start();

$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'xxxx'; 
$db_username = 'xxxx';
$db_password = 'xxxx';

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)    
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)   
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

 $scope_type = implode(",",$_POST["scope_type"]);

    $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];




$sql="INSERT INTO supplier_scope (user_ip, scope_type)
    VALUES ('$ipaddress', '$scope_type')";  

$result = mysql_query($sql); 

$sql2="UPDATE supplier_session SET form2_completed = 'Yes' WHERE form2_completed = 'No' AND user_IP = '$ipaddress'";

$result2 = mysql_query($sql2); 


 if($result){

    header("Location: index.php?registration=success");

}else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

Comment: why not using json to store your checkbox values ?

Comment: i've never heard of it and wouldnt know how to use it :(

Comment: just use in php json_encode($_POST["scope_type"])

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$scope_type = implode(" ",$_POST["scope_type"]);
```

instead of

```
$scope_type = implode(",",$_POST["scope_type"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Still you could do a search in table if your values are comma separated in a column.

For that use,

```
select * 
from TABLENAME 
where FIND_IN_SET('mechanical', COLUMNNAME)
```

Also storing delimited values in table is not that good. Have a look into this

[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace function to use space instead of comma.